# MPI.Gather call hangs for large-ish arrays

Tags: python, openmpi, mpi4py

I use mpi4py to parallelize my Python application. I noticed that I run into deadlocks during `MPI.Gather` whenever I increase the number of processes or the involved array sizes too much.

#### Example:

```
from mpi4py import MPI

import numpy as np

COMM = MPI.COMM_WORLD
RANK = COMM.Get_rank()
SIZE = COMM.Get_size()


def test():
    arr = RANK * np.ones((100, 400, 15), dtype='int64')

    recvbuf = None
    if RANK == 0:
        recvbuf = np.empty((SIZE,) + arr.shape, dtype=arr.dtype)

    print("%s gathering" % RANK)
    COMM.Gather([arr, arr.size, MPI.LONG], recvbuf, root=0)
    print("%s done" % RANK)

    if RANK == 0:
        for i in range(SIZE):
            assert np.all(recvbuf[i] == i)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Executing this gives:

```
$ mpirun -n 4 python bug.py 
1 gathering
2 gathering
3 gathering
0 gathering
1 done
2 done
```

while processes 0 and 3 hang indefinitely. However, if I change the array dimensions to `(10, 400, 15)`, or run the script with `-n 2`, everything works as expected.

Am I missing something? Is this a bug in OpenMPI or mpi4py?

#### Platform:

- OSX Mojave
- OpenMPI 4.0.0 (via Homebrew)
- mpi4py 3.0.1
- Python 3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just noticed that everything works fine with MPICH via Homebrew. So, in case anyone runs into a similar situation on OSX, a workaround is

```
$ brew unlink open-mpi
$ brew install mpich
$ pip uninstall mpi4py
$ pip install mpi4py --no-cache-dir
```

Then, I had to edit `/etc/hosts` and add the line

```
127.0.0.1     <mycomputername>
```

in order for MPICH to work correctly.

**Update**:

By now, this issue should be fixed. [The bug was reported](https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/issues/6258) and updating OpenMPI to 4.0.1 fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks! I had the same problem and this solution did the job!